# Understanding Sprite distance using Raycast in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm adding sprites in a 3d scene using three.js and I want to know distance between the camera and sprite when I click on screen. So I use a Raycater.

But if I click on the sprite, the distance property of intersection object is always "wrong" (someting like 0.3), or maybe I don't know how to read and understand the result. I thought "distance" value of intersection is the distance from camera to sprite (so, in my case something like 5).

Here is a shortened version of my code :

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(new THREE.SpriteMaterial({color: 0x00ff00}));
scene.add(sprite);

camera.position.z = 5;

var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();

window.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    if (e.target == renderer.domElement) {
        var vector = new THREE.Vector3((e.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
        var projector = new THREE.Projector();

        projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);

        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());

        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([sprite]);
        console.log(intersects[0]);
    }
}, false);
```

You can see it in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/pWr57/

So how can I have the distance form camera to a sprite ?

three.js r66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this, instead

```
console.log( raycaster.ray.origin.distanceTo( intersects[0].point ) );
```

Tip: Read the source code, `Raycaster.js`, so you know what it is doing. It is currently returning the perpendicular distance from the sprite center to the ray.

In this case, I agree that it would be better to return the distance from the camera.

three.js r.66